# CSV adding multiple expressions

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv Ive imported as $csv.  Current columns are Title, date, time.

Im adding a column named 'Warning' and want to add another column name DateTime.

How can I add multiple expressions?

Thanks in advance

```
$exportcsv = $csv | Select-Object *, @{
        Name = 'Warning'
        Expression = {
            ([datetime]$_.Time).AddMinutes(-3).ToString("HH:mm:ss tt")
        }
    } 
, @{
        Name = 'DateTime'
        Expression = {
            ("$($_.Date), $($_.Time)" -as [datetime])
        }
    } |     $exportcsv | Export-Csv -Path C:\pathtocsv
```

Comment: You're already doing it ? Maybe you meant to say why `$exportcsv` is null and the answer to that is because `Export-Csv` produces not output

Comment: Remove the pipe `|` from your last line and instead put ` $exportcsv | Export-Csv -Path C:\pathtocsv` on its own line. Other than this detail, your code looks good already.

Comment: Just like the previous comments mentioned, you need to separate the expressions. Swap the pipe for a semi colon.

Comment: My issue is DateTime does not become a column in the CSV... Warning becomes a column, but not DateTime?.

Comment: You mean the DateTime column is there, but with empty values? Show us what the csv contains in columns `Date` and `Time`

Comment: OK you guys are right.  It is working as expected now.
Thanks for your confirmations!